# Check if array sub-keys have empty values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$arr = array(

  'abc' => array(
             'subkey1' => '',
             'subkey2' => false,             
             'subkey3' => 0,  
             ...                          
           ),

  'def' => array(
             'subkey1' => '',
             'subkey2' => 555,             
             'subkey3' => 0,  
             ...                          
           ),

  ...

);
```

I want to unset all parent elements in which ALL subkeys have empty values, like `0`, `''`, `false`, `null`. In my example `abc` needs to be unset.

Currently I'm manually checking within a foreach loop if each subkey is empty, but the if condition is huge because I have 8 subkeys :)

Is there a nicer alternative for this?

Comment: Dont you mean `abc` should be unset in this case?

Comment: What you are doing seems the right way, you could use recursion, but the condition will be as huge as well.

Comment: it has to be done using loops. cant see any other way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$array = array_filter($array, 'array_filter');
```

<sup>[View the output on codepad](http://codepad.org/bFe22vZj)</sup>

```
Array
(
    [def] => Array
        (
            [subkey1] => 
            [subkey2] => 555
            [subkey3] => 0
        )

)
```

---

The outer [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will loop over the array and call the inner [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) on each sub array, which will remove all subkeys which are empty. If each subkey is empty, the outer [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) should then remove the whole sub array.

> If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed.

Comment: I was just about to post this. Also, whenever possible, I find it better to stick with built-in methods over custom ones.

Comment: +1. only thing is this still removes the empty child entries of valid entries. You could use the keys from this result and combine with orig array if thats a prob.

Comment: Good point... but what do you mean by `You could use ... with orig array`?

Comment: `$final = array_intersect_key($origArray, array_filter($origArray, 'array_filter'))`

Comment: It seems it isn't necessary, look at codepads output: http://codepad.org/bFe22vZj The empty subkeys of `def` are still there for some reason.

Comment: I know why, the outer array_filter() won't change any keys, it will only remove whole sub arrays if all it's values are equal to `false`.

Comment: ohhh youre right. I thought your outer func was array_map for some reason

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
foreach ($arr as $index=>$element)
{
  if (in_array(0, $element))
  {
    unset($arr[$index]);
  }
}
```

Comment: How about an explanation about this? ;)